# How to interpret k-means cluster results

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a normalized table (applied minmax scalar) on which k-means of 5 clusters were applied. The last column in the table shows the cluster number. How to infer this for the dimensions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What doe this mean...

```
How to infer this for the dimensions?
```

I'm guessing you want to plot the results, right. Try it like this.

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(df, x="protein", y="fat", color="norm_cluster", size='sodium', hover_data=['norm_cluster'])
fig.show()
```

See the link below for more details.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Clustering%20Algorithms%20Compared.ipynb